# Magento 2: New field in checkout page, find its input value store in which table of database

Tags: checkout, shipping-address, address, table, field

I created a new field **example** in the checkout shipping. [image]

label **example** I  can check in the table **eav_attribte**  like the below images.

[image]

But in which table I can check it's Input value if I put a value **Test** for the field **example**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends entirely on the setup of your extension

See here for example

https://github.com/DominicWatts/OrderComment

I add an attribute but also I add a column to the sales order grid and the value set at checkout is transferred

This process is quite involved. Try to understand as much as you can from my extension. See setup and observer event.

Once the value is in the order grid table you can filter, search and associate to an order a lot eaiser. Which means loading it via block logic for example is more logical.

Comment: awesome, working  for me ... can you guys please guide me step wise how can understand and make this module.?

Answer (score 1):

When you add any custom field in Checkout Page need to add data in mainly two tables.

- quote
- sales_order

For more understanding download module from GitHub and make changes as per requirements.

[Magento2 Checkout Custom Form](https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form)